# Using + sign in replace() and replaceFirst()

Tags: java, regex

**snippet 1**

```
String s = "2+2=4";
System.out.println(s.replace("+", "-"));
```

**snippet 2**

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^\\s+", "")
```

Why in first **snippet 1** `+` is wokring as a symbol, and in **snippet 2** it works like a *regular expression*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [`replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)  takes first argument as `regex`.

Look at the signature

```
replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)
```

Where as [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)  method takes CharSequence  that is just a string.

```
replace(CharSequence target,CharSequence replacement)
```